# How can I make AngularJS rerun a function every time the data it uses changes?

Tags: angularjs

With Knockout, I can say

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: a"></input> +
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: b"></input> =
        <span data-bind="text: result"></span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ExampleViewModel() {
                this.a = ko.observable(5);
                this.b = ko.observable(6);
                this.result = ko.computed(function() {
                    return parseInt(this.a()) + parseInt(this.b());
                }, this);
            }

            ko.applyBindings(new ExampleViewModel());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and `result` will be recalculated every time a and b change.  How can I get AngularJS to do this for me?  I have tried

```
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ExampleCtrl($scope) {
                $scope.a = 5;
                $scope.b = 6;
                $scope.result = function() {
                    return this.a + this.b
                };
            }

</script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
        <input type="text" value="{{ a }}"></input> +
        <input type="text" value="{{ b }}"></input> =
        {{ result() }}
    </body>
</html>
```

After a little more reading, I found `ng-change`:

```
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ExampleCtrl($scope) {
                $scope.a = 5;
                $scope.b = 6;
                $scope.result = function() {
                    return parseInt($scope.a) + parseInt($scope.b)
                };
            }

</script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="a" ng-change="result()"></input> +
        <input type="text" ng-model="b" ng-change="result()"></input> =
        {{ result() }}
    </body>
</html>
```

But that requires me to keep track of the fact that changing `a` or `b` changes `result()`, is there any automatic way of detecting this?

Comment: Have you tried $watch? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `result()` function will be re-evaluated whenever the model changes when binding via  [ng-model](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel) in your inputs like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="a"></input>
```

instead of:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ a }}"></input>
```

Comment: It looks like just using ng-model works (I don't need to specify ng-change), thanks.  Sadly, it updates instantly.  Is there some way to only update it once the focus leaves the input?

Comment: This post may help with deferring model changes to when the focus leaves the input: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11870341/1207991