# How to create on-change directive for AngularJS?

Tags: events, angularjs

Normally ng-model updates bound model each time user pushes the key:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="entity.value" />
```

This works great in almost every case.

But I need it to update when onchange event occurs instead when onkeyup/onkeydown event.

In older versions of angular there was a ng-model-instant directive which worked same as ng-model works now (at least for the user - i don't know anything about their implementations).
So in older version if I just gave ng-model it was updating the model onchange and when I specified ng-model-instant it was updating the model onkeypup.

Now I need ng-model to use on "change" event of the  element. I don't want it to be instant. What's the simplest way of doing this?

**EDIT**

The input still has to reflect any other changes to the model - if the model will be updated in other place, value of the input should reflect this change.

What I need is to have ng-model directive to work just like it worked in the older versions of angularjs.

Here is an explanation of what I'm trying to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/selbh/EPNRd/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here I created onChange directive for you. **Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/sunnycpp/TZnj2/52/

```
app.directive('onChange', function() {    
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:{'onChange':'=' },
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('onChange', function(nVal) { elm.val(nVal); });            
            elm.bind('blur', function() {
                var currentValue = elm.val();
                if( scope.onChange !== currentValue ) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        scope.onChange = currentValue;
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };        
});
```

Comment: But I still want it to be updated when the model will be changed somewhere else. onchange directive can be found in angularui (ui-event="{ change : 'changeCallback()' }), I'm aware of that.

Comment: It does get updated, Try it. That is how it is working with two text-box in demo.

Comment: it it possible to use this directive inside an another directive??

Comment: When using this on a input[type=file] I get this error message: Error: The operation is insecure.

Answer (score 4):

See also: the AngularJS ngChange directive.

When applied to an <input> the changes occurs after each key press not on the blur event.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngChange

Comment: OP: "I need it to update when onchange event occurs instead when onkeyup/onkeydown event."

Comment: It's also worth noting that `ng-change` does not in fact bind to the `change` event in JavaScript. It actually sets a `$viewValue` change listener within the `ng-model` system. Not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

[Angularjs: input[text] ngChange fires while the value is changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868393/angularjs-inputtext-ngchange-fires-while-the-value-is-changing) : This answer provides a much better solution that allows the custom directive to work with `ngModel` so you can still use all of the other directives that go along with `ngModel`.

Also, an even more flexible solution that allows for specifying the event to use (not just blur) and other properties should be built in to angular very soon: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2129

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this, but you can achieve this using a custom directive (on any jquery event you want)

```
<input type="text" ng-model="foo" custom-event="bar" />
<p> {{ bar }} </p>

// create the custom directive

app.directive('customEvent', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var dest = attrs.customEvent;

        $(element[0]).on('any-jquery-event', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // on the event, copy the contents of model
            // to the destination variable
            scope[dest] = scope.foo;

            if (!scope.$$phase)
                scope.$apply();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: i dont think this works with recent angularjs. I get an error scope.apply() function doesnt exist.