# How to event listener in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-video

How to add event listener in AngularJS? I'm working on video tag with AngularJS, it's my code:

HTML

```
<video id="video" width="400" controls>
   <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onchange);
function onchange (evt) {
   document.getElementById("video").pause();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the angularjs code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477904/how-to-create-on-change-directive-for-angularjs

Comment: @MoshFeu lol.  :P :P

Comment: To create event listeners in AngularJS use the [on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) of jqLite. For more information, see [AngularJS jqLite API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angular-s-jqlite)