# How to let ng-model not update immediately?

Tags: binding, angularjs

Code:

```
<input type="text" ng-modal="name" />
{{name}}
```

When I input something into the `input`, the following `{{name}}` will change immediately. Is it able to configure it only update the `name` after I input all characters and leave the input?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs: input\[text\] ngChange fires while the value is changing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868393/angularjs-inputtext-ngchange-fires-while-the-value-is-changing)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Update**

As many have mentioned Angular now has built-in support for this using the `ng-model-options` directive. See more [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions).

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" />
```

**Old answer below:**

There's no built-in option for ng-model to change that behaviour, but you can write a custom directive doing it. @Gloopy wrote a directive like that [for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868393/angularjs-inputtext-ngchange-fires-while-the-value-is-changing). You can look at the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w6jwL/1/).

The directive unregisters from the `input` and `keydown` events which trigger the update after each keystroke.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-model-onblur />
```

Update:

Updated fiddle to use latest stable AngularJS (1.2.16 as of writing), instead of directly referencing the master version at github.

Also added an explicit priority so that the directive is run after `ng-model` to ensure event listeners are changed correctly.

Comment: The fiddle is not working as expected. It updates as you type

Comment: Note: Angular has built in support for this now. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Comment: If there's a way to change the accepted answer to @manikanta it'll be great.

Answer (score 53):

*This is about recent additions to AngularJS, to serve as future answer.*

Angular newer versions (now in 1.3 beta), AngularJS natively supports this option, using `ngModelOptions`, like

```
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { default: 500, blur: 0 } }"
```

[NgModelOptions docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)

Example:

```
<input type="text" name="username"
       ng-model="user.name"
       ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {default: 500, blur: 0} }" />
```

Comment: It doesn't work correct in 1.3 beta 5, but fixed in current master build 2602

Comment: any options using 1.2 version? coz the fiddle people post about overriding input element doesn't work anymore.

Comment: works properly with the current beta version ( 1.3.0-beta-13 )

Comment: Note: The 'default' and 'blur' are 2 separate options. Specifying them both leaves it as 'default', not 'blur' (v1.3)

Comment: That's because I love angular :D

Answer (score 9):

A better option is to use the ng-model-options:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" />
```

Comment: this, however, being the 'right' way only works in newer versions of angular that no longer support ie8... kind of a killer in a lot of dev env :/

Comment: You should simply kill IE8. Google dropped support in 2012.

Comment: I have the same problem with two fields (user and password) in a form, I want to update when click on login button not on blur or typing characters, my problems is that each time that ng-model update the iphone scroll the page to the top

Comment: @s.Daniel +1. If the world keeps supporting IEs from the past, the world might end up using W95

Answer (score 5):

Working directive code(ng-1.2RC3):
use:
    `ng-model-onblur`

```
.directive('ngModelOnblur', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      priority: 1,
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          if (attrs.type === 'radio' || attrs.type === 'checkbox') { return; }
          var update = function () {
              scope.$apply(function () {
                  ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(element.val().trim());
                  ngModelCtrl.$render();
              });
          };
          element.off('input').off('keydown').off('change').on('focus', function () {
              scope.$apply(function () {
                  ngModelCtrl.$setPristine();
              });
          }).on('blur', update).on('keydown', function (e) {
              if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                  update();
              }
          });
      }
  };
})
```