# change event in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a very simple app:

```
app = angular.module("GetTravelTime", ["ngResource"])


app.config ($routeProvider) ->
  $routeProvider.when("/",
    {
      templateUrl: "assets/pages/partials/home_controls.html"
      controller: HomeCtrl
    }
  )

@HomeCtrl = ($scope) ->
  $scope.data = {
    address: ""
  }

  $scope.change = (event) ->
    console.log $scope.data.address
```

home_controls.html

```
<section class="controls" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
<input type="text" placeholder="Location name or Post Code" ng-model="data.address" ng-change="change()"/>
</section>
```

What I am trying to do is when the input field is changed I want to trigger an event but only when the user has finished typing. At the moment each keystroke triggers the change event. I would like it so when they have finished typing it then triggers the event.

In jquery I would do something like click out of the box. Is there a neat way to do this in angular?

Comment: See if this does what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11870341/215945.  Otherwise you can define a `blur` directive -- just search for `[angularjs] blur` on SO.

Comment: You could also set a timeout (using the [`$timeout`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout) service) to only trigger the event after the user has paused for a certain length of time. Depends on your use case.

Comment: thanks guys I will investigate and report back

Comment: it does seem like a lot of code for a simple thing, i wonder if we can simplify it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs: input\[text\] ngChange fires while the value is changing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868393/angularjs-inputtext-ngchange-fires-while-the-value-is-changing)