# Angularjs: how to make input[text] ngModel delay valued while typing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a textbox with `ngModel` binding, like this:

`<input type="text" ng-model="typing" />`

and value of this texbox

`value: {{ typing }}`

I want the model delay to update value while i'm typing. Maybe if I stop type in 500ms, the model will update all value (all things I typed in textbox). 
I make some google but no luck. Anyong has any idea? please help.

**EDIT**

This [Angularjs: input[text] ngChange fires while the value is changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868393/angularjs-inputtext-ngchange-fires-while-the-value-is-changing) doesn't give  solution for my case. It bring solution update value after blur, but I want the value update after stop typing, not blur textbox.

**EDIT 2 (Answers)**

With angular version 1.4, directive `ngModelOptions` is useful in my case. I can write like this `<input ng-model="typing" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default', debounce: {'default': 500, 'blur': 0} }" />` to delay update value to model 500ms in default and update immediately if lost focus.

Comment: that solution bind event blur, so when you blur, the value will be updated. But in here, I want it update after stop typing, not blur from textbox.

Comment: Take a look at this answer here, which provides a directive that allows you to put a delay on ng-change: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121460/angular-directive-encapsulating-a-delay-for-ng-change/21420441#21420441. You can use ngChange to update the model with an ngDelay of 500 ms.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The tidiest way to handle this is probably to write a directive which wraps up the `<input>` element and adds the delaying behaviour. Here is a directive I wrote for the same purpose:

```
angular.module('MyModule')
    .directive('easedInput', function($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div><input class="{{externalClass}} my-eased-input" type="text" ng-model="currentInputValue" ng-change="update()" placeholder="{{placeholder}}"/></div>',
            scope: {
                value: '=',
                timeout: '@',
                placeholder: '@',
                externalClass: '@class'
            },
            transclude: true,
            link: function ($scope) {
                $scope.timeout = parseInt($scope.timeout);
                $scope.update = function () {
                    if ($scope.pendingPromise) { $timeout.cancel($scope.pendingPromise); }
                    $scope.pendingPromise = $timeout(function () { 
                        $scope.value = $scope.currentInputValue;
                    }, $scope.timeout);
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

This directive would be called in your HTML like so:

```
<eased-input value="myValue" timeout="500" placeholder="Please enter text..." />
```

Dissecting the directive:

### Timeout Service

This directive uses angular's `$timeout` service to handle timing: it is an injectable, mockable, idiomatic alternative to calling `setTimeout`. This service is injected in the directive constructor.

### Attributes

The directive accepts three attributes: `value`, `timeout` and `placeholder`.

The `value` attribute here binds to a variable on the scope of the controller which owns the enclosing 'context'. In this case it binds to `myValue`, i.e. to `$scope.myValue` on whichever controller is in charge of this code. It has a two-way binding, denoted by the `'='` entry in the `scope` property of the directive. This means that when this directive updates `value`, the change is propagated up to the controller which owns the directive; hence, `$scope.myValue` will change when `value` is changed inside the directive.

The `timeout` and `placeholder` attributes have one-way bindings: the directive reads their values from the attributes but does not alter them. They are effectively configuration values.

### HTML Template

The `template` property on the directive shows the HTML which will be generated in its place once Angular compiles and links it. It's basically just an `input` element with some special and not-so-special attributes. The value in the input box is bound to the `currentInputValue` variable on the directive's `$scope` via `ng-model`. The `change` event on the input box is bound to the `update` function on the directive's `$scope` via the `ng-change` directive.

### Link function

The guts of the process lie in the `link` function on the directive: we define an `update` method. As stated above, this method is bound to the `change` event of the input box within the directive's HTML template. Thus, every time the user changes the input in the box, `update` is called.

This method uses the `$timeout` service. It tells the `$timeout` service to wait for `timeout` milliseconds, then to apply a callback which sets `$scope.value = $scope.currentInputValue`. This is similar to calling `setTimeout(function () {$scope.value = $scope.currentInputValue}, timeout)`.

The `$timeout` call returns a promise. We are able to cancel a promise `p` produced by `$timeout` which is waiting to execute by calling `$timeout.cancel(p)`. This is what `update` does in its first line: if we have a promise from a previous change event, we cancel it before creating a new one. This means that if we have e.g. a 500ms timeout, and update gets called twice, with the calls 400ms apart, we will only have one promise waiting to fire.

### Overall result

The promise, when resolved, sets `$scope.value = currentInputValue`; i.e. it sets the 'outwardly visible' `value` property to have the value of the contents of the input box. `value` will only change -- and external controllers will only see `value` change -- after a quiescent period of `timeout` milliseconds, which I believe is the behaviour you were after.

Answer (score 13):

If you're okay with having a second property in your model, you can use `$scope.$watch` together with a `debounce` function:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="typing" />
<input type="text" value="{{ typed }}" />
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.$watch('typing', debounce(function() {
    $scope.typed = $scope.typing;
    $scope.$apply();
}, 500));
```

You can write your own debounce function, or use an existing one. There's a good implementation [here](http://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls/), or, if you happen to be using undescore.js, [you're already set](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce).

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bVJK8/) example.

**UPDATE:** Angular 1.3 has now a built-in way to debounce user input: [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions).

Comment: Nice. Proxy to the rescue. :) +1

Comment: Nice one. But I noticed something: If I set the second field, the second field "loses" the binding. To reproduce in your fiddle, write something in the first one, then in the second and afterwards in the first again. Is this a bug or just some strange behavior?

Comment: @RaphaelMüller Nice catch. I don't know why that's happening. If you inspect the markup you'll see that the second input's value property is correctly set. I should have used `ng-model` instead, though. Anyways, in Angular 1.3 there's no need to do any of that since the framework has now a built-in solution for that problem.

Comment: @MichaelBenford thanks, and I will take a look at this new option tomorrow. I hope that's what I'm searching without dirty hacks and so on.

Comment: The new Model Options from angular 1.3 are what I was looking for. They make Life easier.