# Change when Angular.js updates $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've recently started using Angular.js for a project. I have an `<input>` element bound to a variable in my controller's `$scope` using `ng-model`. The default behavior of Angular.js is to update the value in `$scope` as I type. I was hoping to be able to change Angular's behavior to update the value in the `$scope` after I unfocus the input.

Knockout.js works like this by default, so if you're familiar with Knockout, that might help explain what I'm trying to do. Is there any way to change Angular's behavior with this?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868393/angularjs-inputtext-ngchange-fires-while-the-value-is-changing ?

Comment: Hi Mikel, no, I didn't see that, but it looks like exactly what I'm looking for. Let me give it a try. Thanks!