# Angular input inside of directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular directive that I'm building with some pagination controls.

```
<div>
    <!-- table logic here -->
</div>
<div>
    <button bg-click="current=prevPage(current);">Prev</button>
    <input ng-model="current" />
    /{{pages}}
    <button bg-click="current=nextPage(current);">Next</button>
</div>
```

It works fine, but of course when you change the value in the `input`.

It will also pick up the empty string during the delete before you enter a new value in.

#### Is there a way to sniff that out in the directive before it actually fires the change in the `current` value.

Comment: how do you listen the change of your variable `current`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just check the value of the variable `current` before do pagination.

I assumes that you are using `$watch()` to listen the change of your variable `current`.

code inside your directive's link,

```
scope.$watch("current", function(newVal, oldVal){
    if(angular.isNumber(newVal)){
        // your variable is a number
        // Do your pagination here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I maybe understand wrong your question. 
This will update the model only when you click outside the input

```
<input ng-model="current" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" />
```

---

Or another way, when you change the input value it call a function who test if the new value is valid and set it in current.

Html :

```
 <div>
     <button bg-click="current=prevPage(current);">Prev</button>
     <input type="number" ng-model="currentInput" ng-change="changeCurrent()" />
     /{{pages}}
     <button bg-click="current=nextPage(current);">Next</button>
 </div>
```

Controller :

```
 $scope.currentInput = $scope.current; 
 $scope.changeCurrent = function(){
   if ($scope.currentInput!=""){
    $scope.current = $scope.currentInput;
   }
 }
```

Comment: If I delete the value completely the `current` value still fires regardless of the function call.

Comment: That's why you need the `debounce` I described.

Comment: my bad, error in typo in the input ng-model. i update

Comment: Ok, that make sense. Isn't there just a `ng-change="changeCurrent(this.value)"`. Seems a lot more straight forward then binding in this situation.

Comment: Just found a problem with this, since `currentInput` has no value set, now I can not initialize the input field.

Comment: strange i can. you can initialize currentInput  with current. i update the answer

Answer (score 0):

`ngModelOptions` is useful in such a case. You could write like this

```
<input ng-model="current" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default', debounce: {'default': 500, 'blur': 0} }" />
```

to delay update value to model 500ms in default and update immediately if lost focus.

That question also has been answered [several times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868393/angularjs-inputtext-ngchange-fires-while-the-value-is-changing), so you should be able to find further information in the other questions.

UPDATE:

```
$scope.$watch(
   function() {
      return $scope.current;
   }, function(oldVal, newVal) {
      if (!newVal) {
         $scope.current = oldVal
      }
   }
);
```

If `oldVal` is also null or an empty string, you could copy `$scope.current` to another scope variable (say `$scope.savedCurrent`) whenever newVal has a value and copy it back to `$scope.current` if not.

Comment: ok, this seems just like a delay. What if the user deletes the input and just leaves it blank for some time (few seconds, maybe more, who knows). I don't want the list to go empty. It should only update on a valid integer and do nothing for anything else. To add, I would like to check it against `> 0` and `less < pages` count. So would need somewhere to intercept this without firing the change in `current`.

Comment: OK, I think I understand better now. You could establish a watch-function that listens for changes and in that watch-function either copy the value to a scope-variable or use the oldval to reset the previous value. See my update if you think this would work.

Comment: Oh, and switching the input to `<input type="number" ng-model="current" />` would help with the user entering text instead of numbers, you could at least use the attribute `min="1" to limit it to numbers greater than zero.